# Calculating age and checking that values are ok

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need to do a HTML page using  HTML form and JavaScript in which person enters their birth date in form dd.mm.yyyy. When the person clicks "Check" button, the program calculates his age and prints it as a year (like 32). (Rounding to the nearest year, upwards or backwards).

Rules are:
The input field is not allowed to be empty; it should include only numbers; the length of the value must be right; dd must be between 1-31; mm between 1-12 and yyyy between 1900 and 2019.

Here is my code so far and it it not working (I have not got more far yet). How could I improve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Check your age</title>
</head>

<style>


</style>

<script>

 function check(){
  let data = "dd/mm/yyyy";
  let x = data.split("/");

 if(x.value == "" || x.value == null || isNaN(data) || dd < 1 || dd > 31 || mm < 1 || mm > 12 || yyyy < 1900 || yyyy > 2019){

 alert("Give a proper birth day!");
 return false;

 }
 return true;
 }


</script>

<body>

    <form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        <Date of birth : <input type="text" value="" id="dateofbirth" name="time" onclick="check()"/>


    </form>
      <button onclick="check();">Check the age</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: instead of `type='text'`, You can simply use `type = 'date'` [`Input type date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

Comment: I tried. Only thing which this does right is that it prints the words:"Give a proper birth day!"

Comment: Take care in spelling JavaScript to avoid search collision with Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can use date input to get the date from the user. Once you get the value, you can then compare the difference in years and month from today's date.

```js
var dob = document.getElementById('dateofbirth');

function check() {
  var today = new Date();
  var birthDate = new Date(dob.value);
  var y = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
  var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
  console.log(`${y} years and ${m} months`);
}
```

```html
Date of birth : <input type="date" value="" id="dateofbirth" name="time" />
<button onclick="check();">Check the age</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made one of these before. Here is the code which is functional and figures the age in years, months and days. It greets you as "Jesus" if you type in all zeros - feel free to use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Acme" rel="stylesheet"> 
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Age Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>


<style>
body {
  background-image: url('cake.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Acme', sans-serif;
}
</style>


<script>
//document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/cake.jpg')";
//document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/cake.jpg')";  
let birthYear = prompt("Enter Your Birth Year");
let birthMonth = prompt("Enter Your Birth Month (As A Number)");
let birthDay = prompt("Enter Your Birth Day");
let date = new Date();
let currentYear = date.getFullYear();
let currentMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
let currentDay = date.getDate();
let yearAge = currentYear - birthYear;
let monthAge = currentMonth - birthMonth;
let dayAge = currentDay - birthDay;
let monthPluralizer = "";
let dayPluralizer = "";
if (monthAge === 1) {
  monthPluralizer = "Month";
} else {
  monthPluralizer = "Months";
}
if (dayAge === 1) {
  dayPluralizer = "Day";
} else {
  dayPluralizer = "Days";
}
if (currentMonth < birthMonth) {
  monthAge = monthAge + 12;
  yearAge = yearAge - 1;
}
if (currentDay < birthDay) {
  monthAge = monthAge - 1;
  if (currentMonth === 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 10 || 12) {
    dayAge = dayAge + 31;
  } else if (currentMonth === 4 || 6 || 9 || 11) {
    dayAge = dayAge + 30;
  } else if (currentMonth === 2) {
    dayAge = dayAge + 28;
  }
}
if (currentMonth == birthMonth && currentDay < birthDay) {
  monthAge = monthAge + 12;
  yearAge = yearAge - 1;
}
document.write("<h1><p>Your Birth Date Is " + birthMonth + "/" + birthDay + "/" + birthYear + "</p></h1><br>");
document.write("<h1><p>Today's Date Is " + currentMonth + "/" + currentDay + "/" + currentYear + "</p></h1><br>");
document.write("<h1><p>You Are " + yearAge + " Years, " + monthAge + " " + monthPluralizer + " & " + dayAge +
  " " + dayPluralizer + " Old.</p></h1><br>");
if (birthMonth == 0 && birthDay == 0 && birthYear == 0 ) {
  document.write("<h1><p>Hello Jesus!<p></h1>")
} else if (birthMonth === null && birthDay === null && birthYear === null ) {
  document.write("<h1><p>Hello Jesus!<p></h1>")
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```